# Text doesn't show up on GtkLabel

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

I have this code:

```
using Gtk;

class ConquerLauncher : Gtk.Application {
    protected override void activate() {
        var window = new ApplicationWindow(this);
        window.add(new InputList());
        window.show_all();
    }
}

public int main(string[] args) {
    return new ConquerLauncher().run(args);
}

class InputList : Box {
    public InputList() {
        this.set_orientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        var listStore = new Gtk.ListStore(1,typeof(Label));
        var treeView = new TreeView.with_model(listStore);
        this.pack_start(treeView);
        this.pack_start(new InputBox(this,listStore));
        var column = new TreeViewColumn();
        column.set_title("Foo bar's");
        treeView.append_column(column);
        treeView.set_model(listStore);
    }
}
class InputBox : Box {
    public InputBox(InputList list,Gtk.ListStore store) {
        this.set_orientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        var entry = new Entry();
        this.pack_start(entry);
        var button = new Button.with_label("Add foo bar");
        this.pack_start(button);
        button.clicked.connect(() => {
            var text = entry.text;
            entry.text = "";
            TreeIter tp;
            store.append(out tp);
            store.set(tp, 0, new Label(text), -1);
            this.show_all();
            list.show_all();
        });
    }
}
```

What I want to do:

I want to create some sort of input form consisting of three elements:

In an `Entry` the user should write some text. If the presses the button, it should be added to the `TreeView` with a `ListStore` as a model.

Expectation:

The user enters a text, presses the button, the contents of the `Entry` are added to the TreeView and the text input field is cleared.

Reality:

Everything works, except the label that is added to the TreeView is blank.

Before:

[image]

Here an example input:

[image]

After pressing the button:

[image]

Comment: I found out, I have to implement a `CellRenderer`.